# How do I automatically set Window 10 background image based on current month?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to use a specific image file as the background on my machine based on the month of the year. For example, if I had image files:
January.png
February.png
March.png

Then I would want January.png to be my background during the month of January, February.png to be my background during the month of February, and so on. Ideally, I'd like to set something up on Windows 10 such that the image for the current month is set automatically.

I know Windows 10 natively supports setting a slideshow as your background, but the longest refresh period it offers is a single day, where I need a month (which is not a single consistent amount of time).

Is this possible to do without implementing any third-party software?

Comment: I think that you will need to write code (of some form) to make this happen wihtout 3rd party.  Even if this code is a simple script like batch or powershell.  Use the info from [this page](https://www.windows-commandline.com/change-windows-wallpaper-command-line/) to set the background from the script.  Then use the task scheduler to run the script as often as you would like.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the month value in a number `MM` and based on the month 12 = December, apply the background in the background path and add to registry. Copy this into a notepad document, save as a .ps1 and then you can use task scheduler to run it once a day or once a month or something.

```
$month = get-date -format "MM"

if ($month == 01) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background01.jpg /f }
if ($month == 02) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background02.jpg /f }
if ($month == 03) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background03.jpg /f }
if ($month == 04) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background04.jpg /f }
if ($month == 05) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background05.jpg /f }
if ($month == 06) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background06.jpg /f }
if ($month == 07) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background07.jpg /f }
if ($month == 08) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background08.jpg /f }
if ($month == 09) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background09.jpg /f }
if ($month == 10) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background10.jpg /f }
if ($month == 11) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background11.jpg /f }
if ($month == 12) { reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  C:\background12.jpg /f }
```